# Debugging a struts code before Action class is invoked

Tags: debugging, tomcat, web-applications, struts-1

I have a webapp, which uses struts 1.1. For some reasons my app is very slow. The tomcat access logs, show the time taken for each request. This ranges from 12 seconds to 40 seconds.

I inserted a timestamp in the entry and exit of my action class for a request.I observed,the time difference to be hardly 100 milliseconds.But the access logs, shows the time as 30 seconds for the same request.

I am not sure, where I should be debugging now. I tried setting the debug level in web.xml and server.xml etc. Still I do not find any helpful log prints. Is there a way to debug struts code before it lands in my action class?

Comment: Use a filter? They're easy.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the database profilers to check the database hits. Apply index or cluster indexes in improve performance of your database. Use the transaction properly to reduce the database hits.